# Visual C++ #pragma warning

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, pragma

I have the following three consecutive warnings:

```
Warning C4068 unknown pragma ...\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\comutil.h  53
... 54
... 54
```

The related lines are:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4290)
#pragma warning(disable: 4310)
```

The Platform Toolset is the usual v140 and the  Target Platform version is 8.1. The warning level is W3.

I read the current #pragma warning documentation.

As I understand the first line saves  the current state of warning settings.
The following two lines  disable the warnings 4290 4310 for the code ahead until a `#pragma warning(pop)` restores the previously saved state.

Why does `#pragma warning` appear as unknown?

Comment: @HansPassant: Right you are! A GNU project, not assuming there might be a  `#pragma warning`,   defines a `warning` macro conflicting with the preprocessor. If you make your comment  into  answer, I can close the thread, and a coding strategy from an expert for this type issues would be welcomed too.

Comment: Surely you can write the answer yourself now that you know the reason?  You don't need my help anymore.  Just flag the comment as [obsolete].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project's Property Pages I set

```
C/C++ -> Preprocess to a file -> Yes (/P)
```

I rebuilt the project, which produced a Debug dir with a `*.i` file for each C++ file, containing  all macros  expanded (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx)).
The files are very large, but they also contain useful `#line` directives showing when the compiler accesses and exits from a header file.  So I *grepped* for the name of the  header file raising the error and I was able to detect that the `warning` in  `#pragma warning(push)`  had been expanded too, which caused the not found warning.

Since I had included a number of headers from a third party GNU project (where this type of `#pragma` is not defined), it  was relatively simple to find the `#define warning` macro raising the compiler warning.